# SubView added to the contentView of UITableViewCell is removed after Scrolling?

Tags: ios, ipad, uitableview

In my application I load a tableView with an array and I've added an UIButton to each row as subView for my need. I know that the reused cell will have the added button So keeping this fact in mind I've Implemented the  -cellForRowAtIndexPath method like below

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{   
    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"surgeon"];
        if (!cell) {
            cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"surgeon"];
        }
        [[cell.contentView subviews] 
                  makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
                             //before adding button to the contentView I've removed allSubViews
        UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(142, 4, 28, 28)];

        [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"infoicon.png"]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [btn setSelected:YES];
        [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkbtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [btn setTag:indexPath.row];

        if (indexPath.row==1) {
            NSLog(@"CELL %@ CONTNTVEW %@",cell.subviews,cell.contentView.subviews);
        }
        [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
        return cell;
}
```

My problem is that the TableView is loaded well at first time But when I scroll the TableView the Button I have added is Removed even though the removing of subView is done before adding the Button as subView help me  to get This work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It appears that removing all of the subviews of the cell's content view is causing the cell to re-create its cell content when you set the text. I've managed to reproduce the problem, and fixed it by using this method instead:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"surgeon"];
  if (!cell) {
    cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"surgeon"];
  }
  for(UIView *subview in cell.contentView.subviews)
  {
    if([subview isKindOfClass: [UIButton class]])
    {
      [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
  }

  //before adding button to the contentView I've removed allSubViews
  UIButton *btn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
  [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(142, 4, 28, 28)];

  [btn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"infoicon.png"]] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
  [btn setSelected:YES];
  [btn addTarget:self action:@selector(checkbtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
  [btn setTag:indexPath.row];

  if (indexPath.row==1) {
    NSLog(@"CELL %@ CONTNTVEW %@",cell.subviews,cell.contentView.subviews);
  }
  cell.textLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
  cell.textLabel.text=@"A surgeon.";
  [cell.contentView addSubview:btn];
  return cell;
}
```

Important note: if you plan on doing any further cell customization, you'll need to remove them manually in the loop as well.

Comment: If I plan to enable The delete Option of tableView how can I differentiate it from the Button I have added

Comment: You could do a number of different approaches - the simplest is probably to set the tag of the button to a hardcoded constant, and then use that as the way of identifying if that's the button you added or not.